# Coalesce columns in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I did an algorithm and I got a lot of columns with the name *logic* and *number suffix*, I need to do `coalesce` but I don't know how to apply `coalesce` with different amount of columns.

Example:

```
|id|logic_01|logic_02|logic_03|
|1 |  null  |a       |null    |  
|2 |  null  |b       |null    |   
|3 |   c    | null   |null    |   
|4 |  null  | null   |d       |
```

Response:

```
|id|logic|
|1 |  a  |  
|2 |  b  |   
|3 |  c  |   
|4 |  d  |
```

Another example:

```
|id|logic_01|logic_02|logic_03|logic_04|
|1 |  null  |a       |null    |null    |  
|2 |  null  | null   |null    |b       |   
|3 |   c    | null   |null    |null    |    
|4 |  null  | null   |d       |null    |
```

Response:

```
|id|logic|
|1 |  a  |  
|2 |  b  |   
|3 |  c  |   
|4 |  d  |
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First find all columns that you want to use in the `coalesce`:

```
val cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("logic")).map(col(_))
```

Then perform the actual `coalesce`:

```
df.select($"id", coalesce(cols: _*).as("logic"))
```

Comment: Of course, in case of all NULLs in logic_n, if you want to give a default value using coalesce , you may use: 
df.select($"id", coalesce(cols: _*, lit('x')).as("logic"))

Comment: what is column names are different? let's say 5 columns: a, b,c,d,e and we need to coalesce c and e as f so it would look like: a,b,f,d

Comment: @algorythms: Instead of finding the list of columns names from the dataframe, create it yourself. E.g., in your example, you could simply do: `df.select($"a", $"b", coalesce($"c", $"e").as("f"), $"d")`.